# PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Gdata/Extension.php'

Tags: php, zend-framework

For some strange reason I cannot figure out right now, NoEmbed.php fails with a fatal error when trying to include a file. include path is set correctly, I've verified that like below (right before the require_once directive in NoEmbed.php):

```
$s = ini_get('include_path');
$a = explode(':',$s);
foreach($a AS $path) {
    echo $path;
    if(file_exists($path.'/Zend/Gdata/Extension.php')) echo '...found<br/>';
    else  echo '...not found<br/>';
}
```

which outputs "found" within the location expected.

I must admit that I'm currently unable to think of any reason why this should happen, especialy since NoEmbed.php is included correctly. I've encountered similar problems with caching solutions, but they've all been deactivated or uninstalled by now without making any difference.

Edit: I just found that it works with "require" vs "require_once" (then throwing a redeclare error)... any possible reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions and owner of the repertory where are the files, and the files ones two.

for instance dir could be 755 and files 644, with www-data as owner if you want to write into them.

Comment: permissions are fine. See my edit - it works with include. I've now discovers that "clearstatcache()" solves the problem around 99% of the time, but there's still occurances of the same fatal error even then. I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something...

Comment: I would have upvoted this for the first sentence, but then I rad the second one. It should be exceptional when you allow files to be writeable by the webserver uid - and you should never **ever** include code from a file writeable by the webserver uid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was faulty hard drive. I could see the file and its contents with terminal, yet PHP gave me this specific file not found error in 60% of hits.

I have moved it to another hard drive and the error disappeared.